# Node-Red. Get items from object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, node-red

I am working in node-red program and I use an OPCUA node that returns in the payload an array of objects.

[image]

I need to get some variables of the objects, for example, the nodeId of the item; and I try with the next format:

```
var newMsg = { payload: msg.payload[0].item.nodeId };
return newMsg;
```

But it does not work.I can see the error "Error: invalid identifierType in NodeId : 2"
I tried a lot of formats but I do not find the correct way.

Do you know How I could get the data of the array of objects?

Thanks.

Comment: [Here](http://node-opcua.github.io/api_doc/0.2.0/files/packages_node-opcua-nodeid_src_nodeid.js.html) you can see that this error is thrown if the `identifierType` is not valid. But since you just want to use the program this most likely doesn't help you. You could try to get other values and on earlier levels to see if that isn't working either.

Comment: If I need to get the value of the array, is the next format correct?

Comment: msg.payload[0].item.nodeId

Comment: What version of node-red are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the newer versions of Node-RED (after v0.19 iirc) you can get the path to a value from the debug sidebar by placing the mouse over and clicking on the option that pops up.

[image]

The `>_` icon copies the path to the object (relative to selection in the debug node, so normally `msg.payload`). In the example `payload[0].foo`.

This can be used in a function node as `msg.payload[0].foo`